# How to change to order the subplots?

Tags: octave, matlab-figure

For any number of rows and columns.

Vertical subplots are down and to the right.

```
subplot(3,2,i)
1 4
2 5
3 6
{1 4 2 5 3 6}
```

Horizontal subplots are to the right and down. (default)

```
subplot(3,2,i)
1 2 
3 4 
5 6
{1 2 3 4 5 6}
```

How to get the first (vertical) layout?

Comment: AFAIK the layout is hard-coded and cannot be changed. Assuming `subplot(n,m,i)`, you can use the following formula to address the subplot at row `irow` and column `icol`: `i = (irow-1)*m+icol`

Answer (score 2):

For `subplot(m,n,..)`, `kv` being your vertical linear subplot index, the corresponding usual horizontal one is `k = 1 + n*(kv-1) + (1-m*n)*fix((kv-1)/m)`;

Example:

```
m = 3; n = 2;
for kv = 1:m*n
    k = 1 + n*(kv-1) + (1-m*n)*fix((kv-1)/m);
    subplot(m,n, k); title(sprintf("#%d", kv));
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the default layout is hard-coded and can not be changed. A convenient way to address a particular subplot location is to use its row and column indeces as we would do for a matrix. The formula to get the index `i` in `subplot(n,m,i)` at row `irow` and column `icol` is:

`i = (irow-1)*m+icol`

This can be defined in an inline function that you call instead of subplot:

```
mysubplot = @(n,m,irow,icol) subplot(n,m,(irow-1)*m+icol)

figure(1)
n = 3; m = 2;
for icol = 1:m
    for irow = 1:n
        mysubplot(n,m,irow,icol); title(sprintf("%d   %d", irow,icol));
    end
end
```

[image]